# How important is the thesis document for judges on the day of the thesis defense?

Tags: thesis, defense, thesis-committee

I want to defend my thesis in the computer networking field on master degree . all things are done. And now I want to write my thesis document. Is this document important for judges in the defend day or not to evaluate my thesis.

I ask this question because I think they just pay attention to your suggested method and result and presentation.

Is the document are so important for them? because if they do not pay a lot attention to that I do not like take a lot of effort on that maybe you say that I can put that on the internet for any citation By our language is not English.

If the answer is yes. I mean they pay attention to the document in case of evaluating my thesis. What parameter are important for them. Or better to say, I should bold which part or how to write my thesis in order to the judges pay attention to that? and they say themselves this student try hard and I should give him good score ( D: )

Comment: I suspect the answer to this relies entirely on your university's rules. For example, I know a university where the oral presentation/defense has at most a marginal effect on the mark, while the thesis document is the main or only result that gets graded. Other universities certainly have different rules.

Comment: The answer to this question is probably country-dependent. Let's say that your thesis should be at least good enough to be approved by your supervisor.

Comment: Why not to write it seriously? It is one your permanent records!

Comment: "All things are done. And now I want to write my thesis document." Um. If you've not written your thesis, all things are *not* done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is this document important for judges?

You are really asking the wrong question. Any official document that bears your name **eternally** is **important for you** and your future. You are a MSc student with probably small number of publications (if any) and a MSc thesis is an important milestone on your transition from a student to a researcher. It is also a quite large document (much larger than the typical scientific publication), so writing an excellent document at this scale is a valuable lesson even if you want to work in industry, where technical reports / documentation and deliverables are quite common.

Conclusively, you must always strive for excellence and always do the best you can. You must change your student mindset from "Would doing A would get me a better grade" to the adult mindset "Is this really the best I can do **within the time constraints I have** or could I do better?". So you should focus on producing the best thesis document you can (within your time constraints)  regardless of how lenient the committee might be on judging it.

Comment: An excellent answer, though I have one very minor remark: "a MSc thesis is an important milestone on your transition from a student to a researcher" - the OP does not seem to give any indication that he or she wants to become a researcher. Your explanations are just as valid for any other further career path, of course.

Comment: "the adult mindset "Is this really the best I can do within the time constraints I have or could I do better?" -- and then later reach the expert mindset, "will this do, and if so what else could I more productively spend the remaining time on if I stopped now instead of using all available time on this?" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I have written three master's theses, out of which one turned out to be mostly for my own interest, one turned out to be pretty much useless, and the third was actually passed on to my later PhD supervisor. The latter scenario may happen when you decide to proceed in academia, or perhaps even in industry - future employers may show interest in it to assess your strengths and weaknesses.

In any case, for future employers theses, and for that matter your theses-supervisors (being potential referees), are **far more important** than any of the grades you made on any of your exams. So personally, I would say, **yes MSc theses are important** for your later **career**.

The answer by @Alexandros may be a more direct answer to your question, mine may be providing a more long-term drive to deliver a qualitatively good thesis!

Comment: Chris the guy was fishing for a response repeating the same question over and over again with the moderators approval. I did as best I could to point out that the effects of music are psychological and not universal, bound to whatever we originate unlike drugs there are no innate properties.

Comment: The "illusion" has not been shown to be universal